# Make component disappear with negative margins

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a setup in my WPF application that looks like the following.

```
<StackPanel>
    <StackPanel Name="slidingPanelOneHolder">
        <Grid Name="slidingPanelOneHeader" Width="300">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="9*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="Header"/>
            <Button Grid.Column="1" Style="{StaticResource BackButton}"/>
        </Grid>
        <StackPanel Name="slidingPanelOne" Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=slidingPanelOneHeader}">
            <TextBlock Text="Hi"/>
            <TextBlock Text="Hi"/>
            <TextBlock Text="Hi"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </StackPanel>
    <TextBlock>Rest of stuff</TextBlock>
</StackPanel>
```

This produces the following layout.

[image]

I have created an animation so when I press the button it offsets the top margin to make the `slidingPanel` move up. However, my issue is that the `slidingPanel` is still visible when it is moving through the header and anything else above that.

To try and fix this I have tried using opacity masks on both `slidingPanelOne` and `slidingPanelOneHolder`. The main issue with both opacity masks is they move with the margin. Also with the opacity mask on `slidingPanelOneHolder` it didn't actually prevent the text blocks from being seen in the header text block in the first place. Which, in hindsight, is fairly obvious.

Any feedback on how this could be achieved would be greatly appreciated.

Visual of attempts that did not succeed (mid animation)

[image]

And a visual of the desired result (mid animation)

[image]

---

Edit: I am aware that I could give the header a solid white background and a higher z index than the `slidingPanelOne`, however, as there could easily be other components above the header that can't be changed, this is not a viable solution.

Comment: I don't follow what the intended result is. What's your animation doing and what is it supposed to do?

Comment: @Andy Hi, sorry if I did not make it clear enough. The animation is changing the margin of `slidingPanelOne` from `Margin="0, 0, 0, 0"` to `Magin="0, -50, 0, 0"`. My issue there, as you can see in the second image with the failed attempts on, the text blocks that are children of `slidingPanelOne` are still visible once they move past the header and other components. I am trying to make it so that it looks like the desired result image

Comment: You've still not actually given me enough to reproduce this easily.  The panel is defined later in the XAML so it has a higher z-order. If you explicitly set Grid.ZIndex then you could make it below the Header. You probably also need a white fill rectangle in the same cell but I should think it'd go behind that.

Comment: Try putting the text inside a `Canvas` with its `ClipBounds` set.  That should prevent anything inside the `Canvas` from  overdrawing as it animates beyond the bounds.

Comment: @BradleyUffner Thank you for the suggestion. I shall try that first thing in the morning and let you know

Comment: @Andy Thanks for the suggestion but I'm afraid that is not viable as this is going to be used in several different situations where manually setting the z order for every component to make sure it doesn't overlay anything is not easily feasible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to [Bradley Uffner](https://stackoverflow.com/users/526724/bradley-uffner) for getting me to this answer.

The example code below will result in this being shown.

[image: Working Example]

For achieving something like this, you can use the clip component of whatever you are using. For me it looked like this.

```
<StackPanel>
    <Grid Name="slidingPanelOneHeader" Width="300">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="4*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="Header"/>
        <Button Grid.Column="1" Content="Press Me"/>
    </Grid>
    <StackPanel Name="slidingPanelOneHolder" Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=slidingPanelOneHeader}">
        <StackPanel.Clip>
            <RectangleGeometry>
                <RectangleGeometry.Rect>
                    <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource clipConverter}">
                        <Binding ElementName="slidingPanelOneHolder" Path="ActualWidth"></Binding>
                        <Binding ElementName="slidingPanelOneHolder" Path="ActualHeight"></Binding>
                    </MultiBinding>
                </RectangleGeometry.Rect>
            </RectangleGeometry>
        </StackPanel.Clip>
        <StackPanel Name="slidingPanelOne" Margin="0, 0, 0, 0">
            <TextBlock Text="Hi"/>
            <TextBlock Text="Hi"/>
            <TextBlock Text="Hi"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </StackPanel>
    <TextBlock>Something Else</TextBlock>
</StackPanel>
```

You can see this working by changing the margin on `slidingPanelOne` from `Margin="0, 0, 0, 0"` to `Margin="0, -25, 0, 0"`

---

Please note that this example uses a convertor so that the height and width of the clip can be binded. The converter looks like this.

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Data;

namespace YourNameSpace
{
    public class ClipConverter : IMultiValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            return new Rect(0, 0, System.Convert.ToDouble(values[0]), System.Convert.ToDouble(values[1]));
        }

        public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

And it can be used in your XAML document by using the following line in your XAML document's resource dictionary.

```
<local:ClipConverter x:Key="clipConverter"></local:ClipConverter>
```